# Storing floats in NSMutableArray gives unexpected results

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios4

I am writing a method which calculates the average time interval between a series of events (specifically, button tapping in iPhone). Since the number of time intervals I want to average might change during the program's life-cycle, I am storing the time readings in an object named `tapTimes` of type `NSMutableArray` so I don't have to worry about managing the array size.

When I store the time readings as doubles, everything works ok (for simplicity, in the following example I am interested only in one time interval):

```
CFAbsoluteTime time = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
[tapTimes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:(double)time]];
[tapTimes removeObjectAtIndex:0];
double deltaT = [[tapTimes objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue] - [[tapTimes objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
```

Which, for tapping every second or so, gives (the first value is just the first time reading since the array is initialized with zeros):

```
deltaT 311721948.947153
deltaT 1.023200
deltaT 1.080004
deltaT 1.055961
deltaT 1.087942
deltaT 1.080074
```

However, if I store floats:

```
CFAbsoluteTime time = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
[tapTimes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(float)time]];
[tapTimes removeObjectAtIndex:0];
float deltaT = [[tapTimes objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] - [[tapTimes objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
```

Then I get unexpected results for `deltaT`:

```
deltaT 311721760.000000
deltaT 0.000000
deltaT 0.000000
deltaT 0.000000
deltaT 0.000000
deltaT 32.000000
deltaT 0.000000
deltaT 0.000000
deltaT 0.000000
```

Any idea what goes wrong? (I am doing mt first steps in Objective-c/cocoa, so I hope the answer is not too trivial :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `float` is not precise enough to tell one timestamp from a timestamp a second later. Stick to `double`; there's a reason that `CFAbsoluteTime` uses that type.

Here's a demonstration of the problem under 64-bit 10.6.4:

```
val: 311721760.000000 - val2: 311721761.000000 - (val2 - val): 1.000000
v: 311721760.000000 - v2: 311721760.000000 - (v2 - v): 0.000000
```

The first line used `double` values; `val2` was generated by adding `1` to `val`. The second line used `float` values. The source code follows:

```
//clang so_float.m -o so_float
#import <stdio.h>

int
main(void) {
  double val = 311721760.000000;
  double val2 = val + 1.0;
  fprintf(stderr, "val: %f - val2: %f - (val2 - val): %f\n", val, val2, val2 - val);
  float v = val;
  float v2 = val + 1.0;
  fprintf(stderr, "v: %f - v2: %f - (v2 - v): %f\n", v, v2, v2 - v);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just checking I got it right:: If I use (IEEE 754) single precision floats to represent my **time** readings, I have 23 bits of resolution for the fractional part of the mantissa. since 2^-23 is approx. 1e-7, I cross the '1 second' resolution limit for an exponent of approx. 24, since 2^24 ~ 1.6e7, which is approx. 6 months (translating seconds to months) after the reference date of Jan 1 2001 00:00:00 GMT. So, I am about 9 years late after the last chance of using floats with 1 second resolution :)